# Python: Apply both cumsum and product to pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with LTD and CycleCount columns and need to fill CycleSum column like this:

```
LTD         CycleCount    CycleSum
1/1/2017    1             1
1/1/2017    1             1
2/1/2017    0             1
2/1/2017    0             1
3/1/2017    1             2
3/1/2017    1             2
4/1/2017    1             3
4/1/2017    1             3
```

I tried to do:

```
df['CycleSum']=df.groupby('LTD')['CycleCount'].prod()
```

to get unique LTD with 1/0 values in CycleCount and this is OK as the first step for me, because I got a group:

```
LTD         CycleCount
1/1/2017    1
2/1/2017    0
3/1/2017    1
4/1/2017    1
```

But I can't find a way how to make a cumsum on this group and then transform it back to original dataframe.

CycleCount can be only 1 or 0 and the same for the each LTD. But CycleSum must increase for any different LTD with CycleCount=1
It is easy to do in Excel but difficult to realize in Python for me.

Any suggestions? The purpose to make all in one action

PS I'm former VBA developer and maybe this is a noob case, but it is extremelly difficult to go away from Excel logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the `groupby` + `prod` followed by `cumsum` then `join`

```
df.join(df.groupby('LTD').CycleCount.prod().cumsum().rename('CycleSum'), on='LTD')

         LTD  CycleCount  CycleSum
0 2017-01-01           1         1
1 2017-01-01           1         1
2 2017-02-01           0         1
3 2017-02-01           0         1
4 2017-03-01           1         2
5 2017-03-01           1         2
6 2017-04-01           1         3
7 2017-04-01           1         3
```

---

These would also produce the same results

```
df.join(df.groupby('LTD').CycleCount.all().cumsum().rename('CycleSum'), on='LTD')
df.join(df.groupby('LTD').CycleCount.max().cumsum().rename('CycleSum'), on='LTD')

         LTD  CycleCount  CycleSum
0 2017-01-01           1         1
1 2017-01-01           1         1
2 2017-02-01           0         1
3 2017-02-01           0         1
4 2017-03-01           1         2
5 2017-03-01           1         2
6 2017-04-01           1         3
7 2017-04-01           1         3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for!